# KafkaStreams consumer assigne exception (IllegalStateException)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have created kafka stream app, but after it start kafka keep rebalancing with this exception till error state:

```
Exception in thread "t-StreamThread-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Consumer was assigned partitions [xxx] which didn't correspond to subscription request [] at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.handleAssignmentMismatch(ConsumerCoordinator.java:218)
```

I use: springboot 2.2.1, kafka-streams: 2.3.0, kafka: 2.3.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say. Could it be, that you different applications with overlapping `application.id` configurations? Are all application instances with the same id exactly the same (including the input topics they subscribe to)?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Not OP, but what you described was the problem for me. 2 separate apps ended up using the same application.id (botched config cleanup) Thanks!